# Permission denied error on git push

Tags: git, github

So in trying to run

```
git push origin master
```

I got the following prompt:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

To which I accidentally said 'no' to. Now, I get the following error message when trying to push:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If anyone could help me figure a way to re-prompt or do it manually, I'd appreciate it greatly!

NOTE: I'm even getting a `Permission denied (publickey).` error when trying the following:

`ssh -vT git@github.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to delete your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. That way, ssh will ask you again to verify the authenticity of url.

However, you will be asked to also verify the authenticity of any other url that was already working.

***EDIT***

Run the following to clean up the entry from your known hosts entries:

```
ssh-keygen -R github.com
```

You seem to have generated the keys using sudo, so the keys are linked with `root` account. Further, it seems to me that you are trying to connect to github using another non root account, so the ssh keys simply don't match. I would suggest generating ssh-keys without sudo, and then adding the respective key to your github account.

Comment: there is no known_hosts file inside .ssh/ ...there was an authorized_keys file that I deleted, but it did not help

Comment: @Murgittroyd can you try running `ssh-keygen -R github.com` and see if that works?

Comment: # Host github.com found: line 1 type RSA
/root/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /root/.ssh/known_hosts.old

Comment: Thanks @mu 無, that kinda worked. It's weird because there still doesn't appear to be a known_hosts file, but it at least asked if I want to continue again after showing the RSA fingerprint. However, even if I say yes, I get a permission denied (publickey) error...

Comment: So I tried git push origin master without sudo and outside root, but get these errors: error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.

Comment: @Murgittroyd that means you created (`clone`d or `init`ed) rhe repo with sudo, and so you are tied to using sudo. I would suggesting doing away with sudo completely, make a fresh clone, or change file ownership to your account, and then proceed. This will only get further painful for you

Comment: Ahh, just changed the owner of the .git folder, it looks clean now, thank you so much @mu 無